# How to display external data using custom form in a Drupal page?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a form custom module for get data from an external url.

`$requestType = drupal_http_request('http://www.example.in/php/example/getSampleType.php',$options);
$loomType =drupal_json_decode($requestType->data);`

This is my Form
[image]

Using this result I have created checkboxes and select a value from checkbox then submit the data.

```
function myForm_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
$url='http://www.example.in/php/example/exampleSort.php';
//$data1 = http_build_query($form_state['values']['check'], '', '&');

$checked = array();
foreach($form_state['values']['check'] as $key => $val) {
array_push($checked, $val);
  }
$mychecked=checking($checked);

$checkedType = array();
foreach($form_state['values']['checktype'] as $key => $val) {
array_push($checkedType, $val);
  }
$loomType=checking($checkedType);

$datas=array("sampleMachine"=>$mychecked, "sampleType"=> $loomType);
$data =json_encode($datas);
$option = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => $data,
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
    );
//$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');

$response =drupal_http_request($url,$option);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

}

I got some result. Now I want to display those results in my drupal page. How can I do that..I am using Drupal 7.

I want to display this in Drupal page in specific format
[image]

Comment: This question is really broad. Typically a form has a build, validation and submit functions as briefly detailed here. https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390 Then you display the results in any 1 of many ways, an example can be found in the Examples module for developers, or similar questions here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54374/how-do-i-print-results-after-submitting-a-drupal-form

Comment: But I didnt understand how to display myresult

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to create a custom module for this, since ... there is a module that can "***display JSON results in a Drupal page**" ... i.e. the [Views JSON Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_json_query) module. Some details from its project page:

> JSON Query is a Views 3 plugin that adds native JSON query generation. It allows you to parse JSON using Views' graphical query builder.
>   It works much like [Views XML Backend](https://drupal.org/project/views_xml_backend) but with JSON.

And a screenprint from that same page:

[image]

For more details, read about it in the article about "[Show external JSON data in Drupal Views](http://frontmag.no/artikler/utvikling/show-external-json-data-drupal-views)".

PS: Similar solution if your input format is XML (instead of JSON), using [Views XML Backend](https://drupal.org/project/views_xml_backend).

Comment: Using this module I can create check boxes ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the equivalent of your "example form" would become an exposed filter of your view. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have installed above mentioned modules and tried to create views. In query settings field I have added  the url http://www.example.in/php/example/exampleSort.php It displaying like this  {
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "node" : {
        "value" : ""
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "value" : ""
      }
    },
    {
      "node" : {
        "value" : ""
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Your last comment really looks like a new question to me, which you shuld post as a new question. Also, looking at your profile I noticed you don't have the "informed" badge. Which is probably also why you're not aware of what's written in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: Thank you for ur information. I am not able to display my Json result using Views JSON Query .

Comment: Should I create custom view for displaying the result. suggest me the best solution for this.

Comment: yes, that's also what is suggested in the linked article: "***Create a new view and choose Json option at Show select box:***"

Comment: I have tried this. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you ***tried***, and explain ***what*** doesn't work (I hope you understand that it is impossible to enhance my answer without such information). Maybe can you edit your answer to include a TEXT-version (not an image) of the JSON (sample) file that you receive from that external URL?

Comment: I have given json file url and rowapath in Views query settings by referring this(Show external JSON data in Drupal Views) article which you share before. But it doesn't give proper result to me. My json array is {"RESULT":"SUCCESS","MACHINES":["Airjet","Waterjet","Rapier"]}

Comment: Try setting the value for "Row Apath" to "/ " (without the quotes). If that doesn't help, try "." (single dot, without the quotes).

Comment: When I setting Row Apath '/' it displays a json structure.  Here what would be the 'key chooser' of field value?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may now have run into the support issue at https://www.drupal.org/node/2457437 (and I don't know what the answer to that issue is either). I also noticed comment #4 in that issue, is that "you" who posted it there? **Hint**: have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2457877#comment-10800662 (comment nr 8), and check if the patch there (in nr 6 attached) does help in your case.

Comment: I have made changes according to  drupal.org/node/2457437 page. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: Is there any other way to display json result in a drupal page?

Comment: Do you have some way to have those data from that external url formatted as XML instead of JSON? Other attempt: is it possible for you to get access to the database where those JSON data are related to, if so what is the format of that database, like is it SQLite, Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL, some sort of PDO compliant database?

Comment: sorry.. I want it in JSON format and I don't have permission to  access the database.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying, I was just trying to find possible alternatives for you (i.e.: via module "forena", you know that one?). I need some more time to do some more experiments / research (I'm interested in finding a way to make "your" JSON sample work also). No guarantee, but if I can get it to work I'll let you know about it).

Comment: ok.. thank you.  I haven't worked with Forena module.

Comment: You don't know what you're missing then ... have a look at some of my answers (tagged with forena) if you want to get an idea. Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it ...

Comment: But Forena module is used to create reports right..

Comment: Yes, creating reports is one of the reasons to use Forena. It can also create Charts. It can "read" the data from a PDO compliant (external) database. And it can also "make" the retrieved data available in either JSON format or XML format (instead of a rpt), and you can export the data in a report to CSV, XLS, PDF, DOC, etc. And your "example form" could be implemented as a "report parameter form".